# If I replace Promises on the global object, what Promises do async/await use?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, ecmascript-2016

Say I replace the global `Promise` object with Bluebird promises (such as to support cancellation). If I then write a function using `async`/`await`:

```
async function foo() {
    const response = await fetch(...);
    const result = doSomethingWith(response);
    return result;
}
```

What kind of Promise is returned here?

IIRC when the code is compiled down to ES5, it will indeed return a cancellable Bluebird promise, since async/await is translated to use the global Promise object internally. But in ES7, where async/await is a native construct, will it use the Promise constructor in the global object, or is it hard-coded to use the native one?

Comment: Please take a look at https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/1026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native syntax will always create native promise objects from the current realm, no matter what value the global `Promise` variable in the realm has.

A transpiler should strive to recreate that experience, however when it also includes a promise shim (which might be configured to be a custom library) that needs to live somewhere and for simplicity will probably depend on the global `Promise` value.